Google "Document" type crashing debugger
I running VS Code 1.93.1 on Windows 11 Pro 23H2.
I am using the Google Document AI API to return a Document type object.
Whenever a Document object would appear in the variables, the debugging server crashes. No logs appear in the debug console or the terminal.
Something similar also happens when trying to log a Document object using something like:
import logging
from google.cloud.documentai import Document
with open(
    "./test_data/documents/redefine_meat/beef_patties/Premium_burger_ocr_document.pickle",
    "rb",
) as f:
    doc: Document = pickle.load(f)

logging.info(f"The document: {doc}")

The FastAPI server running the code doing the logging suddenly rejects all the active connections, but doesn't actually crash, or log anything to the console.
Printing a document object works without issues in the FastAPI case.
Here is a gif of the issue:


The issue ended up being caused by an older version of protobuf (5.28.0).
Updating to 5.28.2 solved the issue.
